# Derivative containing delta term?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

**Consider a low-pressure system centered
on 45 degrees South, whose sea-level pressure field is given
by p = p$_{0}$ - $\triangle p$ e$^{\frac{-r^{2}}{R^{2}}}$ , (2)
where r is the radial distance from the centre, and $\triangle p$,
p$_{0}$, and R are constants. 
Assume ${\Delta}p > 0$ so that this is a low-pressure system.
Assuming constant density and Coriolis parameter 
across the system, determine the structure of the geostropic wind
around this system: specify the sense of
the circulation around this system and find an algebraic ex- pression
for the maximum speed umax of the
geostropic wind and the radius rmax at which it is located. Assuming
P$_{0}$ = 1000 hPa, $\rho$ = 1kg/m3, and a value 
of f appropriate for 45 degrees S, evaluate the numerical
values of umax and rmax for $\triangle p$ = 20 hPa and
R = 500 km. (Hint: appeal to symmetry and work along the x-axis.)**

For geostrophic wind (u,v)=$\frac{1}{f\wp}(\frac{-dP}{dy},\frac{dP}{dx})$

My thinking is trying to evaluate along x axis i.e. y=0.

If 
$$P=1000-\Delta Pe^{-(\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{R^{2}})}$$
is the correct derivative
$$\dfrac{dP}{dy}= \dfrac{2y}{R^{2}}\Delta Pe^{-(\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{R^{2}})}$$ 
given we know $\Delta P$ and $R$ are constants, or does the $\Delta P$ term
have an effect?

Comment: You need to tell us the exact definition of this $\Delta P$.

Comment: Change in pressure and the pressure field is given by P above.

Comment: This is insufficient information. What is the formula ?

Comment: Posted original question

Answer (score 1):

$\Delta P$ is a constant like any other (you even known it is $20$), your derivative is right, though it should be denoted as a partial derivative.

Comment: wait i think this is wrong approach, i want to get umax, and am imagining concentric circles on a plane, ?

Comment: I answered on the computation of the derivative, not on the original question. You should define $u_{max}$.

Comment: I thought an expression for U$_{max}would$
be when $\frac{-1}{f\wp}\frac{2y}{R^{2}}e^{-(\frac{x^{2}}{R^{2}})}=0$

Comment: This is not a definition.

Comment: Umax is the maximum of the geostrophic wind

Comment: Insufficient for a definition. Give a general formula.

Comment: The definition for geostrophic wind is given (u$_{g},v_{g})=$
$\frac{1}{\rho f}(\frac{-\partial P}{\partial y},$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial x})_{z}$
where P is pressure, $\wp$is density and f is corriolis constant

Comment: What is the relation to $u_{max}$ ?

Comment: I guess where calling umax the maximum of the geostrophic wind

Comment: You still don't answer the question. What is the relation between $(u_g,v_g)$ and $u$ or $u_{max}$ ?

Comment: well i thought if you considered just along the x-axis you would have a situation where v=0, so ug= $\frac{1}{ρf}(\frac{−∂P}{∂y})$

Comment: Hem, what about $u$ ?

Comment: im assuming the g subscript has been dropped its a bit confusing

Comment: You should show more rigor.